# R: alternatives to all.equal?

Tags: r, floating-accuracy

While `all.equal` is a very powerful tool, with a cornucopia of informative response strings, I wanted an equivalent function which simply returned TRUE/FALSE for near-equality.   (I'm aware of the standard tricks like `identical(all.equal(foo,bar), TRUE)` ).  I wrote the following code snippet, but was wondering if I'd overlooked a similar function in one of the R packages.

```
approxeq <- function(x,y,tolerance = .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5,...) {
   #Note: better input validation should be written
   if (length(x) != length(y)) stop('lengths must be equal')
   checkit <- abs(x-y) < tolerance
    return(invisible(checkit))
}
```

The main difference between `approxeq` and `all.equal` is that the former gives me element-by-element equality test results. I'm not saying this is better, just different.
So, does anyone know if there is a similar (and presumably more robust) function in a released package?

Comment: `isTRUE(all.equal(x,y))` is a shorthand version of the "trick" you mention.

Comment: If often use the following workaround: `mapply(x, y, FUN = all.equal) == TRUE`.

Comment: For input validation I would do something like `stopifnot(length(x) == length(y), is.numeric(x), is.numeric(y))`